# Firebase Analytics not showing up in console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an android app which has a singleton class within which I want to use a `FirebaseAnalytics` object to collect data.
In the `onCreate` object of the singleton class, I initialise the object by doing the following:

```
    analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());//get firebase analytics instance
    analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);//enable analytics
    analytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(60000);//minimum session is 1 minute
    analytics.setUserId(pref.getUserId());//set user ID
```

I have a method in the singleton class that receives two variables namely `category` and `name`. I have called this method from another activity and tried to set the category and name but it doesnt show up in my Firebase console, only the default collectables are showing:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, category);
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
    //log event
    analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, params);
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make the data collected show in my analytics console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#SELECT_CONTENT) for the SELECT_CONTENT event, you'll see that you're supposed to pass the parameters CONTENT_TYPE and ITEM_ID.